# Filter Data from List<String> in android onTextChange Android

Tags: android, list, listview, filtering

I have little problem with filter data from List.i want to filter data from List. My Problem is wech i start to write text on edittext than the listview shows thw only first posision of the List.

Here is my Code.

MainClass

```
public class ItemType extends AppCompatActivity {

    ListView item;
    Context context=this;
    List<String> allItemNames = new ArrayList<String>();
    Item_Type_list_adapter adapter;
    EditText search;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter1;
    String[] data = {"mehul joisar","amit mishra","amitabh","Aamir khan","jesica","katrina"};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_item_type);

        search=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.Search);

        item=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.item_type_listview);

        allItemNames = new ArrayList<String>();

        allItemNames.add("Coil");
        allItemNames.add("Plate");
        allItemNames.add("Sheet");
        allItemNames.add("Extra");

        adapter=new Item_Type_list_adapter(this,allItemNames);

        item.setAdapter(adapter);


        item.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

                String data = (String) adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i);
                Log.d("Positions", data);

            }
        });

        search.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int i, int i1, int i2) {

                adapter.getFilter().filter(search.getText().toString());
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

            }
        });


    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_item_type, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement


        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

ArrayAdapter Class

```
public class Item_Type_list_adapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> implements Filterable {

    Activity context;
    private final List<String> allNames;

    public Item_Type_list_adapter(Activity context,List<String> allNames) {
        super(context, R.layout.item_type_layout,allNames);
        this.context=context;
        this.allNames=allNames;
    }
    public View getView(int position,View view,ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater=context.getLayoutInflater();
        View rowView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_type_layout, null, true);

        TextView ItemName = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.ItemName);

        ItemName.setText(allNames.get(position));


        return rowView;

    };
}
```

I Add the 4 value in List

1.Coil
2.Plate
3.sheet
4.extra

And when i start filter it only showing the Coil.But When i touch on listview its Log perfect Value But just Showing Wrong value.

Help me to solve this issue.

is there any missing in my code?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try out this code for filtering `ListView` with `EditText`
**activity_main.xml**

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/etText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10">

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:isScrollContainer="false" />
```

a new TextView layout called **item.xml** for showing items

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

</TextView>
```

`onCreate()` method inside **MainActivity**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Array list of items
    List<String> itemsList = new ArrayList<String>();
    itemsList.add("AAAA");
    itemsList.add("AABC");
    itemsList.add("ABCD");
    itemsList.add("BBCD");
    itemsList.add("BCDE");
    itemsList.add("CCDE");
    itemsList.add("CDEF");


    // create an ArrayAdaptar from the String Array
    final ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            R.layout.item, itemsList);
    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    // Assign adapter to ListView
    listView.setAdapter(dataAdapter);

    // enables filtering for the contents of the given ListView
    listView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                int position, long id) {
            // When clicked, show a toast with the TextView text
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    ((TextView) view).getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    EditText myFilter = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etText);
    myFilter.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        }

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                                      int after) {
        }

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                                  int count) {
            dataAdapter.getFilter().filter(s);
        }
    });
}
```

hope it helps

Comment: i don't want to get text from listview.I want to filter data and shown into list view.@SaNtoRiaN

Comment: Any Idea Why i am facing this issue??

Comment: @Rushabh042 Sorry but what do you mean by the only first posision of the List.?

Comment: it means i added the "Coil" at first So it Only Showing The Coil During Filter.@SaNtoRiaN

Comment: its Showing the error java.lang.IllegalStateException: ArrayAdapter requires the resource ID to be a TextView

Comment: listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.simplerow,
    R.id.rowTextView, itemsList);

Comment: But i want to know one thing How can i show Two List With Two Text view in Listview?

Comment: It'll take much code and it's not possible to add all that in a comment. Check out this tutorial http://hmkcode.com/android-custom-listview-items-row/

Comment: exactly thanks for this...its working dude...@SaNtoRiaN